# How do I alert a after the progress bar has completely loaded in angular js & bootstrap ?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to load an image after the progress bar has completely loaded, (kind of sequential). I have this snippet. Please do help!

`<progressbar class="progress-striped active" animate="true" max="100" value="progressValue2" type="success"><i><span count-to="{{countTo}}" duration="1" count-from="{{countFrom}}"></span> / 100</i></progressbar>`

This is in my controller.
    
    `var amt = 100;
    $scope.countTo = amt;
    $scope.countFrom = 0;
    $timeout(function(){
    $scope.progressValue2 = amt;
    }, 200);` 
    // something after the bar has COMPLETELY loaded, I want to do       something..

Comment: so you want to load an image after the timout?

Comment: nope not necessarily, for example I want to start loading another progress bar once the 1st bar loading is done.

Comment: Now you have changed the question with that last comment. Please provide proper details of issue in the question itself. The progress bar is dependent on your data model

Comment: Sorry about that, I was just pointing to "do something after the progress bar has completely loaded". I actually need another progress bar to start  loading once 1st one is done.

Comment: how are you catching the end of progress event? do i create a dummy end of an event to give you the answer or you are only using the timeout for the end of that progress event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should use the promise returned by the timeout:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.progressValue2 = amt;
}, 200).then(function(){
    $scope.showImage = true;
});
```

In your template:

```
<img ng-if="showImage" ng-src="" ... />
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, that works when the progress bar starts loading and the same time Image is loded. I want to load the image after the progress bar has completely loaded.